# linker error libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

Tags: ios7, google-analytics, xcode5, linker-errors, google-analytics-firebase

I have developing mobile app for iPhone uisng xcode5.
I have replaced old google analytics by new version 3.07 `"libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a"` and class files.
I have `"libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a"` file inside my project folder and it is linked in Framework folder also.

On settingPage > Search path itself I have changed `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` and `$(PROJECT_DIR)` in Xcode.
Once i run my xcode it give me linker error as link.

No such directory

```
/Users/Kareems/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EventAheadModel-bfbulwwdciidebbukoyafttnkhil
/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
```

Comment: I have the same issue or something like that...